# Sticky header transition becomes jumpy and ugly when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Check the frontpage of https://www.belkita.com . If you scroll down slowly you can check how to at certain point it becomes jumpy and ugly when it should be as smooth transition to a smaller header.

The javascript code I'm using is:

```
<script>
// When the user scrolls down 50px from the top of the document, resize the header's font size
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};


function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
        document.getElementById("header-sidebar").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("masthead").style.height = "80px";
    document.getElementsByClassName("custom-logo")[0].style.maxWidth = "130px";

  } else {
        document.getElementById("header-sidebar").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("masthead").style.height = "140px";
      document.getElementsByClassName("custom-logo")[0].style.maxWidth = "230px";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is shakie because your div#header-sidebar gets display: none; as you scroll down.

Also add a class if the scrollTop is >50 instead of inline styling because the rest is just css styling.

e.g.:

```css
/* scrolled >50px */
#masthead.scrolledEnough {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

//scrolled <50px
#masthead .notEnough {
    top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the desired behavior is that div#header-sidebar disappears. How can I achieve that without the display:none?
Also, any css code you suggest instead of the inline styling scrollTop >50 ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your condition:

```
 if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50)
```

your first condition is never true, document.body.scrollTop always evaluates to 0. Your second condition is activated, and then the banner size is reduced. when the banner sized is reduced, the second condition no longer passes, and so the banner size is increased. once it increases size, the condition passes again etc etc. in a loop.

Comment: I have removed the first condicion, but I'm still getting the same issue. Do you mind letting me know how to prevent the loop you described? Any code I should include?